# Is this another affix-riddle to Really Bore You?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

My ‘prefix’ is a ‘prime’

My ‘infix’ is a combination of ‘primes’

My ‘suffix’ is found between ‘primes’

My whole is often found at the origin of a very long sequence!

What am I?

Small hint:

> The title holds a very important clue!!

Moderate hint:

> Maybe you have to think top down?

Big hint

> Driving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'be been thinking for a while that the 'primes' in question here are in fact...

> ***primary* colours**, prompted by the secret 'RBY' capital letters in the title (Red-Blue-Yellow).

With the latest hint, I think I see that the three '-fixes' here are actually...

> the **stages of a traffic light** while a vehicle is waiting at a junction. (Certainly in the UK, at least...)

*My ‘prefix’ is a ‘prime’*

> The 'prefix' (first stage) is **RED**, a primary colour and the colour of a stop light.

*My ‘infix’ is a combination of ‘primes’*

> The 'infix' (middle stage) is **RED** and (what we'll call) **YELLOW** (but might more often be called 'amber') combined, the two primary colours that appear together in UK traffic lights to prompt drivers to get ready to move soon.

*My ‘suffix’ is found between ‘primes’*

> The 'suffix' (final stage) is **GREEN**, the colour of the 'go' light, and which - in a rainbow - appears between yellow and blue, two primary colours.

*My whole is often found at the origin of a very long sequence!*

> Traffic lights are often found at the start of a long series of halted cars!

Answer (score 2):

I might be interpreting the clues too literally, but I think it's

> 3.142, aka. pi rounded to three decimal places

Explanation:

> My ‘prefix’ is a ‘prime’

> 3 is a prime number

> My ‘infix’ is a combination of ‘primes’

> 2 and 7 are prime numbers, and 2x7=14

> My ‘suffix’ is found between ‘primes’

> Even numbers (i.e. multiples of 2) can't be prime, so you will invariably find them in between primes.

> My whole is often found at the origin of a very long sequence!

> You can't get much longer than infinity!

I can't figure out how this fits the title or the hints, though...

Comment: My only other ideas are something involving [rot13]pbybhef (urapr gur pncvgnyvmrq EOL va gur gvgyr), or something involving [rot13]Genafsbezref ("cevzrf" cyhf gur "qevivat" uvag), but I can't make either of them fit the clues nicely enough....